# sys/socket.h is not found for gcc arm x86_64-aarch64 cross compiling

Tags: c, gcc, cross-compiling, arm64

I'm trying to cross-compile(via **gcc-arm-10.3-2021.07-x86_64-aarch64-none-elf**) a simple test.c

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    int s = socket(AF_INET, 0, 0);
    printf("socket = %i\n", s);
    close(s);
}
```

with this command

```
/opt/gcc-arm-8.3-2019.03-x86_64-aarch64-elf/bin/aarch64-elf-gcc test.c -o test
```

But it fails with a message:

test.c:1:10: **fatal error:** sys/socket.h: No such file or directory

I even specified the /usr/include directory with `-I` flag but fails to find **asm/socket.h**

Same I tried directly from compiler executable directory (from /opt/gcc-arm-8.3-2019.03-x86_64-aarch64-elf/bin/) but ld fails to link literally any of the symbols in test.c.

Same was tested using **gcc-arm-10.3-2021.07-x86_64-aarch64-none-elf**

Comment: This is a Linux or glibc header file, right? (one of those) I suppose you need the header files for Linux and/or glibc for the ARM platform. Note that you have a compiler which is configured for no operating system. Without an operating system there are no sockets. You don't just need a Linux compiler though, you also need the Linux header files.

Comment: I think that toolchain is for a "bare-metal" target that won't have sockets support included.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [user253751](https://stackoverflow.com/users/106104/user253751) and [Ian Abbott](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5264491/ian-abbott)  answered in comments, there are no header files because there is no operating system which defines "socket" entity.